# ¿por qué cuando iteramos, por ejemplo, un DataFrame, es mucho más rápido hacerlo con numpy o pandas que con un bucle for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base-de-datos, pandas, numpy

Algo en lo que llevo pensando mucho tiempo: Iterar una lista o array o lo que sea, la cosa es iterar.

La pregunta es: ¿por qué cuando iteramos, por ejemplo, un DataFrame, es mucho más rápido hacerlo con numpy o pandas que con un bucle `for`?

Ya sé que numpy trabaja con matrices y vectores, pero no entiendo el detrás de escena (por así decirlo), me refiero a vector, matriz o una cadena simple, después de todo, la PC tiene que iterar una por una, ya sea una lista o una matriz.

Answer (score 4):

Numpy trabaja con implementaciones en C de sus métodos.

En python recorrer un array significa que el programa tiene que ir comprobando el tipo de cada variable, localizándola en memoria y comparándola, ya que cuando creas un array ni especificas tipos ni asignas las posiciones de memoria, todo lo hace python por tí.

Numpy al trabajar con C aloja las cosas en memoria de manera consecutiva y además tiene la ventaja de que es tipado, con lo cual no necesita ir comparando tipos. Te recomiendo leer este artículo ya que explica lo citado anteriormente con algo más de detalle y además menciona el término [Locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), que explica el por qué de acceder a datos secuenciales en memoria es más rápido (entre otras, pero está en inglés también) :

https://www.datadiscuss.com/proof-that-numpy-is-much-faster-than-normal-python-array/